# Meremorphic function on $\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\}$ has dense image?

Tags: complex-analysis

So I am working through some practice problems and I've come across a head scratcher.

Let $K=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac{1}{n}:n=1,2,\dots\right\}$ and $f$ be holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}\setminus K.$ Show that if $f$ has a pole at each point $\frac{1}{n}$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ then the range of $f$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}.$

So since we are looking for dense images I immediately thought Casorati-Weierstrass. (CW), but we don't have that $0$ is an essential singularity. I also thought of maybe imitating the proof of CW, but I don't have that $0$ is even a singularity and it certainly isn't an isolated singularity.

I'm sure if involves assuming that $f$ is not dense, i.e. it must miss all points is some neighborhood of $z_0.$ I just can't seem to get any traction. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes, you can imitate the proof of CW. Suppose the range of $f$ is not dense. Say $|f(z)-a|>r>0$ for all $z$. Let $g(z)=1/(a-f(z))$. Now what sort of singularity does $g$ have at $1/n$? Then what else can you say about $g$ near $1/n$? After you answer that, what about the singularity of $g$ at $0$? And now $g$ contradicts ___ .

Comment: So $g$ would be holomorphic for all $z\in\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\},$ since $|f(z)-a|\neq 0 \forall z\in\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\}.$ Also $g$ is bounded on the disc since $\left|\frac{1}{a-f(z)}\right|\leq\frac{1}{r},$ meaning any singularities it would have must be removable. So $g$ is holomorphic on all of $\mathbb{D}.$ If we rewrite $f(z)=\frac{1}{g(z)}+a,$ we can't draw any conclusions like in the CW because we don't know that $0$ is an essential singularity. Sorry, but I just can't seem to get it right in my head.

Comment: Yes, $g$ has removable singularities at each $1/n$, and after we remove those singularities we see the singularity at $0$ is removable, so $g$ is holomorphic in the disk. Now: What is $g(1/n)$, exactly?

Comment: So we have $g\equiv 0,$ which means $0=\frac{1}{f(z)-w},$ which can't happen since $f(z)\neq w$ as we assumed it was the point that $f$ missed. Correct? Is there any way I can give you some credit for the help even though this is a comment?

Comment: Right. Except $f(z)\ne w$ has nothing to do with why $0=1/(f-w)$ is impossible - that's much simpler, actually: $0$ is not the reciprocal of anything. Don't worry about the points...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

If a disk around $w$ is not in the range, then $g(z) = 1/(f(z) - w)$ is bounded and all its isolated singularities are removable (with value $0$ at those points).  After removing them, you just have a singularity at $0$, which is again removable because the function is bounded in its neighbourhood.  Now $g(1/n) = 0$ for all $n$, and so $g$ is identically $0$ because its set of zeros has a limit point in the domain.  But that can't work, because $g(z) \ne 0$ if $z$ is not one of the original singularities.

Comment: The problem is that we are not given, that 0 is an essential singularity. Hence, I don't see how I can reach contradiction using the fact that $f(z)=\frac{1}{g(z)+w},$ even if $g$ is bound in $\mathbb{D}.$ Also Liouville requires us to have an entire function, which we do not have since we are only in the disc. Also even if we get $g=c\in\mathbb{C},$ this only gives us that $f(z)=\frac{1}{c}+w.$

Comment: Sorry, I've edited to fix this up.